# Sorting DataGridView By Decimal

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sqlite

I know there is numerous post like this one exists but I can't find the right solution. I need to sort the first column of datagridview in ascending order. but sorting order is wrong. the first column is a primary key and contains decimal values.

Below is my sample code. I have tried to change the data type after populating the column, but it's not working.

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class Form1

Dim conn As SQLiteConnection
Dim da As SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim cmdbl As SQLiteCommandBuilder


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Const filename As String = "database.db"
    conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & filename & ";Version=3;")
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select * from 'item_rate' ORDER BY 'SL NO' ASC"

    da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).CellTemplate.ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
    DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), 0)


End Sub
```

Comment: „…it is not working…“ is _always_ a horrible error description.

Comment: First you say "the first column [...] contains decimal values" and then you say "I have tried to change the data type after populating the column". That second statement seems to contradict the first because you wouldn't need to change anything if the column really did contain `Decimal` values. Is it actually the case that the column contains `String` values that are supposed to represent numbers? If so then why are you using text to store numbers in the first place? If you can't change that then you need to actually convert the data.

Comment: yes first column contain decimal value, but hope you may aware that if you auto populate the datagridview columns, by default all the value converted to String, thats why I tried to convert datatype of that particular column to decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have finally found the solution. Instead of changing the column datatype of DGV change the column datatype of DataTable. In order to do this, you need to clone the DataTable and change the column Datatype. You can not change the datatype once your table filled with data. Below is the sample code.

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class Form1

Dim conn As SQLiteConnection
Dim da As SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim cmdbl As SQLiteCommandBuilder


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Const filename As String = "database.db"
    conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & filename & ";Version=3;")
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select * from 'item_rate'"

    da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(table)

    'clone the DataTable to change the data type of a column for sorting

    Dim dtCloned As DataTable = table.Clone()
    dtCloned.Columns(0).DataType = GetType(Single) 'Assign the first column to decimal type AKA Single
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        dtCloned.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    'End Of Clone Table

    'Assign cloned table to DGV
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtCloned
    'Sort DGV
    DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), 0)

End Sub
```